# Adding tooltip for CheckBoxTableCell

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to add a tooltip for the `CheckBoxTableCell` using the "reason" property in my model. How do I do this?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.CheckBoxTableCell;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        TableView<Model> table = new TableView();

        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

        TableColumn<Model, Boolean> column = new TableColumn<>("Column");
        column.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(column));
        column.setCellValueFactory(features -> features.getValue().flagProperty());

        table.getColumns().add(column);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(table);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class Model
    {

        private SimpleBooleanProperty flag;
        private SimpleStringProperty reason;

        public Model()
        {
            flag = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
            reason = new SimpleStringProperty();
        }

        /**
         * @return the flag
         */
        public SimpleBooleanProperty flagProperty()
        {
            return flag;
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty reasonProperty()
        {
            return reason;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a row factory:

```
    table.setRowFactory(tv -> new TableRow<>() {
        private Tooltip tooltip = new Tooltip();
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Model item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty || item == null) {
                tooltip.textProperty().unbind();
                setTooltip(null);
            } else {
                tooltip.textProperty().bind(item.reasonProperty());
                setTooltip(tooltip);
            }
        }
    });
```

The row's `updateItem()` method will be invoked any time the row is used to display a new `Model` instance. Empty rows set their tooltip to null; non-empty rows set their tooltip to the tooltip instance, and bind the tooltip's text to the value in the model. The binding ensures the tooltip is updated if the `reason` changes.

You might want to make the logic a little more sophisticated, e.g. only display the tooltip if the text is non-empty, or if the flag is not set.

Comment: I think a `tooltip.textProperty().unbind()` is necessary to avoid potential "memory leaks".

Comment: @Slaw I think it's ok without, though perhaps prudent to include it. `bind()` will automatically call `unbind()` if there's an existing binding, so the only issue is empty cells retaining references to the last item they displayed after those items are no longer referenced elsewhere (i.e. removed from the table's items). There should only be a small, bounded number of such cell instances. So it's not really a "memory leak", as the excess comsumption can't grow indefinitely.

Comment: True, the effect of _not_ calling `unbind()` is likely small. But doing that kind of cleanup is sort of automatic for me, just in case, so I thought I'd mention it. The problem would only manifest if the model item had a large object graph (or referenced a large amount of data) that would otherwise be GC'd except for this one binding.

Comment: Does this add a tooltip for the entire row? What if I just want the tooltip on the one column?

Comment: This will add a tooltip for the row. Adding a tooltip just for the cell is difficult with your current model, because you have to observe a "sibling property" (i.e. the cell that is displaying `flag` would rely on the `reason` property as well as the `flag` property). The most robust way to do this would be to modify your model. Define an immutable class (or record), e.g. `public record Flag(boolean flag, String reason){}` and then in the model use a `ObjectProperty<Flag>` in place of the two properties you currently have. Then there is a little work to do with the cell factory.

Comment: Details would depend a bit on the usage here. Is the table editable? If so, what happens when a check box is checked? Is there a mechanism to provide a `reason` in that case?

Comment: @James_D table and checkbox is not editable.  The reason is populated from a dropdown in another dialog when the record is edited.

Comment: @trilogy So if you don't want the tooltip for the whole row, I would use the solution outlined above.

Comment: @James_D Ok, with solution, what is the work you need to do in the cell factory?